# How do I make my program in python faster

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project where I need to find the optimal triplets of number (E, F, G) such that E and F is very close to eachother (the difference is smallest) and G is bigger than E and F. I have to make n numbers of such triplets.

The way I tought about it was to sort the given list of numbers then search for the smallest differences then those two will be my E and F after all the n pairs will be done I will search for every pair of E and F a G such that G is bigger than E and F. I know this is the greedy way but my code is very slow, it takes up to 1 minute when the list is like 300k numbers and i have to do 2k triplets. Any idea on how to improve the code?

guests is n (the number of triplets)

sticks is the list of all the numbers

```
# We sort the list using the inbuilt function sticks.sort()

save = guests # Begining to search for the best pairs of E and F
efficiency = 0 while save != 0:
    difference = 1000000 # We asign a big value to difference each time 

    # Searching for the smallest difference between two elements
    for i in range(0, length - 1):
        if sticks[i+1] - sticks[i] < difference:
            temp_E = i
            temp_F = i + 1
            difference = sticks[i+1] - sticks[i]

    # Saving the two elements in list stick_E and stick_F
    stick_E.append(sticks[temp_E])
    stick_F.append(sticks[temp_F])

    # Calculating the efficiency
    efficiency += ((sticks[temp_F] - sticks[temp_E]) * (sticks[temp_F] - sticks[temp_E]))

    # Deleting the two elements from the main list
    sticks.pop(temp_E)
    sticks.pop(temp_E)
    length -= 2
    save -= 1 

# Searching for stick_G for every pair made for i in range(0, len(stick_F)):
    for j in range(0, length):
        if stick_F[i] < sticks[j]:
            stick_G.append(sticks[j]) # Saves the element found
            sticks.pop(j) # Deletes the element from the main list
            length -= 1
            break

> # Output the result to a local file print_to_file(stick_E, stick_F, stick_G, efficiency, output_file)
```

I commented the code the best I could so it would be easier for you to understand.

Comment: Use multiprocessing instead...

Comment: When you find E and F, you know their indexes. Every number with greater index than max(index(F), index(E)) is a G right?

Comment: Yea, this is pretty much what I do, temp_E and temp_F has the postion of the best E and F at that moment. For example in 1 3 5 18 19 25 with 2 triplets to make my program will first find 18 and 19 as a pair, then 1 and 3 as a pair then for 18 and 19 will find 25 then for 1 and 3 will find 5 so at the then the triplets will look like this (18,19,25) and (1,3,5)